# getrusage vs. clock_gettime()

Tags: getrusage

I am trying to obtain the CPU time consumed by a process on Ubuntu. As far as I know, there are two functions can do this job: getrusage() and clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &tp). In my code, calling getrusage() immediately after clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &tp), always gives different results.

Can anyone please help me understand which function gives higher resolution, and what advantages/disadvantages of these functions have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### getrusage(...)

- **Splits CPU time into system and user components** in ru_utime and ru_stime respectively.
- Roughly **microsecond resolution:** struct timeval has the field tv_usec, but this resolution is usually limited to about 4ms/250Hz [(source)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html)
- Available on SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001: this means it is available on both Linux and OS X

[See the man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrusage.2.html)

---

### clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, ...)

- **Combined total of system and user time** with no way to separate it into system/user time components.
- **Nanosecond resolution:** struct timespec is a clone of struct timeval but with tv_nsec instead of tv_usec. Exact resolution depends on how the timer is implemented on given system, and can be queried with **clock_getres**.
- Requires you to link to librt
- Clock may not be available. In this case, clock_gettime will return -1 and set errno to EINVAL, so it's a good idea to provide a getrusage fallback. [(source)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html)
- Available on SUSv2 and POSIX.1-2001: this means it is available on Linux, but not OS X.

[See the man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html)